# Display graph and values in pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

[How can I show values with graph in pivot table as highlighted in attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETasX.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You do this by applying conditional formatting to the values section of the pivot table.

Put your cursor in the pivot table, then use PivotTable Analyze>Select>Entire PivotTable:

[image]

Then use PivotTable Analyze>Select>Values:

[image]

Now use Home>Conditional Formatting>Data Bars> and select the style you prefer to use:

[image]